# List comprehension for dictionaries nested in a list - python

Tags: python, nested, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to extract the city names out of the below dictionary/list and create a new list just of the city names.  So the new list would look like this: cities = ["Paris","Berlin","Tokyo","Sydney"]

I can't even figure out it I need to do this with list comprehension or dictionary comprehension.

```
cities_response_data = {
  "prices": [
        {
          "city": "Paris",
          "iataCode": "",
          "lowestPrice": 54,
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "city": "Berlin",
          "iataCode": "",
          "lowestPrice": 42,
          "id": 3
        },
        {
          "city": "Tokyo",
          "iataCode": "",
          "lowestPrice": 485,
          "id": 4
        },
        {
          "city": "Sydney",
          "iataCode": "",
          "lowestPrice": 551,
          "id": 5
        },
      ]
    }
```

If you could try to explain how the code works as well as what it actually is that would be amazing. I know I'm missing something fundamental here..

These are some of the attempts that haven't worked:
cities = [city for city in cities_response_data["prices"][0]["city"]]

- result: ['P', 'a', 'r', 'i', 's']

cities = [value for (key,value) in cities_response_data["prices"][0]["city"]]

- result: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

cities = [value for (key,value) in cities_response_data["prices"][0].items()]

- result: ['Paris', '', 54, 2]

cities = {city for city in cities_response_data["prices"][0]}

- result: {'lowestPrice', 'id', 'iataCode', 'city'}

cities = {city for city in cities_response_data["prices"][0]["city"].items()}

- result: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

cities = {city for city in cities_response_data["prices"][0]["city"].iterows}

- result - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iterows'

Does it needed to be nested, something like this:
cities = [value for value in ["".join([value for value in cities_response_data["prices"][0]["city"]])]]

- result: ['Paris']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of thinking like the computer.  ;)  You need to loop over the `prices` elements, each of which is a simple dict.

```
cities = [x['city'] for x in cities_response_data['prices']]
```